# How to use result of MDX query in another MDX?

Tags: mdx

I use **MDX** query on **Microsoft Adventure Work DW 2012** AND I want to have the **"SUM" of "Reseller Order Count" in each "country"** for the **"product"s that have "Reseller Order Count" grater than 30 in "Australia"**

in other words,

first I want to find the "Product" s that have **"Reseller Order Count" > 30**

in **"Australia"** then find "SUM" of "Reseller Order Count" for **the finded "Product"s in other countries**

the Measure is

> [Measures].[Reseller Order Count]

and the dimentions are

> [Geography].[Country].[Country]

and

> [Product].[Product].[Product]

Thanks All @};-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do the ozzy filter in a `WITH` clause and then use that in the `SELECT`:

```
WITH
SET [AustraliaProducts] AS
  FILTER(
    [Product].[Product].[Product].Members,
   ([Geography].[Country].&[Australia],[Measures].[Reseller Order Count]) > 30
  )
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Reseller Order Count] ON 0,
  Non Empty 
    [Geography].[Country].[Country].MEMBERS
  * [AustraliaProducts] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Work];
```

I'm a little unsure if then in the results you need Australia or not - if not then a further addition in the WITH clause can filter out Australia:

```
WITH
SET [AustraliaProducts] AS
  FILTER(
    [Product].[Product].[Product].Members,
   ([Geography].[Country].&[Australia],[Measures].[Reseller Order Count]) > 30
  )
SET [exclAustralia] AS
  EXCEPT(
    [Geography].[Country].[Country].MEMBERS,
    [Geography].[Country].&[Australia]
  )
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Reseller Order Count] ON 0,
  Non Empty 
    [exclAustralia]
  * [AustraliaProducts] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Work];
```

Comment: Thank u very much , it helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[AustraliaProducts] as
SUM(
    [Product].[Product].[Product].Members,
    IIF(
        ([Geography].[Country].&[Australia],[Measures].[Reseller Order Count]) > 30,
        [Measures].[Reseller Order Count],
        Null
    )
)

Select 
[Measures].[AustraliaProducts] on 0,
Non Empty [Geography].[Country].[Country].Members on 1
From [Adventure Work]
```

Comment: Hi , thank u for your reply , but its not the answer , I want to filter product by a mdx query then use the result of that query in another query , for example if [Australia] has  [Reseller Order Count]>30 for "produact A" and "product B" then I want to know the sum of  [Reseller Order Count] in other countries like "US","Canada",... for just these two products

Comment: I'm afraid, I think your reply is correct too,Thank u very much :( how can I choose two answers as correct ?

Comment: You cannot. Just choose the best.